# Mathematics program used to make the figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering what kind of program was used to make these graphs / figures ?
I know that the authors used LaTeX.

[image: Figure 0]

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: The authors most likely wrote LaTeX code by hand to produce these figures, such as TikZ code.

Comment: from the arrow tips I would say they used Ipe or Latexdraw

Comment: I think you could make prettier diagrams, with TikZ for example, much smaller, with smaller arrow heads, and with hats only over $a$ and $b$, not over the superscripts. The human eye can take in a lot of information, if it can focus on the entire diagram at once, so paradoxically you should make mathematical diagrams as small as you can as long as none of the features become difficult to identify. Look at Vladimir Arnold's diagrams for wonderful examples of this general idea.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I would add the important bit, that also relations and connections in the diagram need to be clear at first sight. For example the lower part of the above "Figur 3" has the letters and arrows to close to each other as to let easily be distinguished, which letters refers to which arrow.

Comment: Mysigt! (I like the Swedish text)

Comment: My guess is [tag:metapost].

Comment: If you really need to know how these particular figures were made, you'll have to ask the authors.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: the answer was that he did them in OpenOffice draw

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is something which is best answered by asking the original author directly.